# When i try to run java code a run as window pops up with Ant Build options

Tags: java

i am trying to run my java code in code blocks, it was fine all along but now when i run a window saying "run as" pops up with two options both saying "Ant Build". When i select either it fails and says "cant find an Ant file to run". Please help is it settings or what?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using some sort of IDE. Which one? Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Is this within Eclipse?

Comment: @crowne Looks like Eclipse to me. To OP, if you want to launch a `main()` method, you should right click on that file and select "run as Java application" or similar. Ant is a build tool, which I guess you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you dont have the main method in your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Bu default if you haven't configured any `Runtime Configuration` in eclipse, it gives you an option if you have defined the `main` method in your code. If not - you need to explicitly configure the Runtime Configuration and after that the eclipse will show you the option